# Get column name from table in vba access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have written a code for getting the name of the tables present in my access db.
Below is the code:

```
Private Sub Commande49_Click()
    Dim tbl As AccessObject, db As Object
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim strOut As String
    Set db = Application.CurrentData
    For Each tbl In db.AllTables
    If Not Left(tbl.Name, 4) = "MSys" Then
    Msgbox tbl.Name
    End If
    Next tbl
End Sub
```

I want to know how can I retrieve the columns names of each table and display table names and column names in an excel sheet.
Kndly help me on this issue.

Comment: Why the [mysql], [excel] and [excel-vba] tags? Do you want to do this in Access or Excel or MySQL?

Comment: I am working on Access and DB is in Access and i want result in Excel

Answer (score 1):

If your current code works (while I wouldn't have written it that way) and if your `db` is a `DAO.Database`, you can add:

```
    for each f in db.tabledefs(tbl.name).fields
        debug.print f.name
    next f
```